# Flutter for fedora 37

Tags: linux, flutter, fedora

I'm trying to install flutter on Fedora 37 with snapd but it's not working. Whenever I try to use the command:

```
sudo snap install flutter --classic
```

I get the error:

> Classic confinement requires snaps under /snap or symlink from /snap to /var/lib/snapd/snap.

Then I run the command:

```
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
```

I get the error:

> Failed to create symbolic link "snap/snap": File exists.

How do I fix this or find another way to use flutter on Fedora 37?

```
[ninal@fedora ~]$ sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/snap/snap': File exists
[ninal@fedora ~]$ sudo snap install flutter --classic
error: cannot install "flutter": classic confinement requires snaps under /snap
       or symlink from /snap to /var/lib/snapd/snap
[ninal@fedora ~]$
```

Answer (score 4):

Sudo or not, `ln -s` will always fail if the link file already exists. In order to overwrite there is a `--force` option you can use overwrite an existing link file.

However, the error message `"snap/snap": File exists.` indicates that you already have a directory named `/snap` in which a new `snap` symlink is attempted to be created.

So `ln` behaves in two different modes, either the last argument is the name of

1. the link file or
2. a directory where the link file is to be created within

```bash
$ cd /tmp
$ mkdir -p a/b/c
$ ln -s /tmp/a/b        # First time, create "b" symlink in /tmp
$ ln -s /tmp/a/b        # Second time, fails since symlink exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link './b': File exists
$ ln -sf /tmp/a/b       # Succeds, overwrites existing symlink
$ mkdir c
$ ln -s /tmp/a/b/c c    # First time, create "c" symlink inside /tmp/c directory
$ ln -s /tmp/a/b/c c    # Second time, fails since symlink exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link 'c/c': File exists
$
```

---

For your particular scenario you need to get rid of the existing `/snap` directory to create the expected symlink.

```bash
sudo mv /snap /snap.old
sudo ln -s /var/lib/snapd/snap /snap
```